# Parsing single string argument that has space in bash

Tags: bash, shell, eval

What is the best way to parse single string argument(that has space in between) to a bash script ?

```
#!/bin/bash

eval $@
echo $OPT1
echo $OPT2
echo $OPT3
echo $OPT4
```

eval works fine when the options are of one word like below

```
./args.sh 'OPT1=1 OPT2=2 OPT3=3 OPT4=4'
 1 2 3 4
```

But not when my arguments are like below

```
./args.sh 'OPT1=1 OPT2=2 OPT3=3.1 3.2 OPT4=4'
```

What is the better way of parsing the above agruments?

Please note that I have no control over the input arguments, I am using third party binary which just generate these arguments as a single string.

Is there any command similar to eval that will do the parsing based on some delimiter in my case'='

Comment: What happens to the `3.2`?  Is it part of `OPT3` or is it to be treated as a separate argument?

Comment: It should be part of OPT3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`eval` is always dangerous.  There is, fortunately, a much safer and more reliable way to define variables and that is to use `declare`.

Try this script:

```
$ cat args.sh
#!/bin/bash
old=$IFS
IFS=$'\n'
declare "$(sed -E 's/ +([[:alnum:]]+=)/\n\1/g' <<<"$*")"
IFS=$old

#Verify that declare was succesful:
declare -p OPT1 OPT2 OPT3 OPT4
```

We can run the script to verify that it works as desired:

```
$ ./args.sh 'OPT1=1 OPT2=2 OPT3=3.1 3.2 OPT4=4'
declare -- OPT1="1"
declare -- OPT2="2"
declare -- OPT3="3.1 3.2"
declare -- OPT4="4"
```

#### How it works

- `#!/bin/bash`

  This shebang line specifies bash as the shell
- `old=$IFS`

  This saves the old value of IFS.
- `IFS=$'\n'`

  This sets IFS to be just a newline character.
- `declare "$(sed -E 's/ +([[:alnum:]]+=)/\n\1/g' <<<"$*")"`

  The sed command reformats the input to put each declaration on a separate line.  The output is suitable as arguments to `declare`.
- `IFS=$old`

  This restores the old value of IFS.
- `declare -p OPT1 OPT2 OPT3 OPT4`

  This is a diagnostic statement so that we can verify the variables have been defined as we want.